# Screen on ubuntu restarts over and over

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm new to Linux and I have face a problem when I tried to run Ubuntu distibution on Oracle VM VirtualBox. All the time the screen is kind of shutting down and going back to normal after several seconds the problem is only when I have some app open. It seems for me to be a problem related to ubuntu not the virtual machine ( I have a 8GB RAM for the VM and the overall procesor usage is low).[Ubuntu screen crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auGxI.png)
I also can't use software update tool after several minutes of installing updates it gives output that it can't install updates and during the installation many of the features that it try to install gives back a ,,Authentication failed"software updater problem[updater problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq5Wv.png)

I will really apreciate any help or direction where I should search for the source of the problem

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 here inside VMware Workstation and it is very reliable. Make sure the Host Video driver and BIOS are up to date. Make sure you do not install drivers inside the Ubuntu guest - it gets its drivers from the Host via Virtual Box.  Make sure the guest internet is good. Updater should should work. Try (command terminal)  sudo apt-get update and authorize then sudo apt-get upgrade .  Let finish and sudo reboot and see how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication failed is a mismatched checksum on the package. This is probably due to poor implementation of Hyper-V support by VBox (HV support is still in beta). I suggest you use: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` to turn off Hyper-v, reboot, and try again.

I have been experiencing similar issues myself recently, however I was forced to move my VM setup to Hyper-V due to requiring Docker for development.

Good luck.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it the problem is still active but right now I also have an output that there is an internal error with gnome-shell